# Login Screen Authentication error with more then 1 user

Tags: android

I am creating a login screen for my application with more than 1 authentication. Now when i login the app with the first name and password, then it works but when i try the other names and password then it force closes the application.

I am using If and Else for the login Screen.

```
if (uName.equals("A") && uPass.equals("123")) 
{
    Intent cardSummaryScreen = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Hi.class);
    b = new Bundle();

    EditText text1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputUserName);
    b.putString("name", text1.getText().toString());
    hi.putExtras(b);

    startActivity(hi);
}

else if(uName.equals("sumit") && uPass.equals("456")) 
{
    Intent cardSummaryScreen1 = new
    Intent(LoginActivity.this,Hi.class);

    Bundle c= new Bundle();
    EditText text2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputUserName);
    c.putString("name",text2.getText().toString());

    startActivity(cardSummaryScreen1);
```

Comment: Could you paste the stacktrace from LogCat? That might give us a clue what might be going wrong. Just knowing that the program force closes doesn't help much. We'd like to know with what kind of error it force closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you didn't post a stacktrace, I think I can see where your app gets the error and force closes.

In your second `IF/ELSE` statement, you try to add extra data to your new `hi1` intent.
However, you're trying to add `b`. This does not exist in your second statement, only in the first.

Therefore your app is trying to add data that doesn't exist, giving it a `NullPointerException` and force closing.

```
Intent hi1 = new
              Intent(LoginActivity.this,Hi.class);


              Bundle c= new Bundle();

              EditText text2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputUserName);

              c.putString("name",text2.getText().toString());
              hi1.putExtras(b); // b does not exist. This causes a NullPointerException
              startActivity(hi1);
```